# Placement new when passed insufficient memory pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just wondering how placement new would behave when it is passed a buffer thats not sufficient for allocation. But it seems like it succeeds anyway. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <new>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        char data;
        char data1;
};


int main() {
    printf("sizeof MyClass: %lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(MyClass));

    void *place = malloc(sizeof(MyClass) - 2);

    MyClass *ptr = new (place) MyClass();

    ptr->data = 10;
    ptr->data1 = 20;
    printf("%d\n", ptr->data1); //This seems to have work fine, storing the data as always
}
```

Is this the expected behavior? Somebody please explain how come this works. Thanks.

PS: I'm using a 64 bit Ubuntu system, g++ compiler.

Comment: Undefined behaviour like writing past the end of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling placement new on a block of memory that isn't big enough for the type is undefined behavior. It can (and likely will in a real program) trash your heap.

Undefined behavior is undefined, so the program can *appear* to proceed as normal, even though you're likely trashing memory that doesn't belong to you. Your simple example doesn't even attempt to free the memory it allocated, so you never really test the heap to see if it was corrupted.

Comment: Any operating system worth their salt will kill any process if it tries to write to memory that it does not own. So a segfault is much more likely than actually thrashing the memory of another process.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I didn't say anything about trashing the memory of _another_ process. I didn't say anything about processes at all. By "own" and "heap", I didn't mean the OS's concept of memory ownership and heap (ie: pages of memory from the virtual memory table assigned to a process). I meant `malloc`'s heap and what `malloc` considers to be your memory.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel But trashing a bit over a buffer, or random memory that is allocated to your program, can just screw up your program. Valgrind will still catch it though, and a segfault definitely is likely.

Comment: @Nicol I was refering to the "thrashing memory that doesn't belong to you". If it doesn't belong to you, it belongs to someone else, and you'll get a segfault. You can't write to memory you don't own.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Again, "you" does not mean "your process". You're thinking in OS terms, not C++ standard terms. The specifics of what malloc and the OS do is completely irrelevant to the standard. You the C++ program are allowed to touch only the memory you have explicitly requested. Any other memory addresses either do not exist or are not for you. It doesn't matter which, because you didn't allocate them so they don't belong to you. I neither said nor implied that you could touch another processes memory; I said that you were not legally allowed to touch memory that you did not allocate.

Comment: It's very possible to write to memory that is mapped to your local process but which is not memory that you are supposed to be writing to.  Doing that will not trigger an immediate segfault, because the segfault mechanism is based on watching which pages your process reads/writes to, and this particular error involves writing to a page that your process owns.  In practice, the result of doing that can range from (no observable symptoms) to (corrupt data causes a segfault later on) to (no crash, just strange behavior).  Subtle bugs like that are what cause C++ programmers to age prematurely :)

Answer (score 2):

Placement new has nothing to do with allocation. It doesn't know nor does it care how big the buffer you pass is - its only job, really, is to call the constructor on an object that shall begin its allocation (and presumably fit at) the address you passed to it.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. Yes, the actual placement new just calls the constructor. But you cannot construct an object on memory that you don't own. So while the placement new itself isn't technically the problem, placement new is what allows the problem to manifest.

Comment: But that's the point I'm making. It's a dumb function. It doesn't know or care what you pass it - that's your job.

Comment: My point is that what you said is _why_ the behavior is undefined. It's misleading because you never actually say that it does in fact cause undefined behavior. Only that it calls the constructor on memory that's too small for the object.